# Run Flutter builder runner in compiled app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an idiot question. is it possible to run the build runner in an application compiled for dynamic code generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Flutter application, no.

Flutter apps neither have the ability to dynamically evaluate Dart code, nor do they have access to the tools needed to parse and generate source code.