# Flutter code into APK/IPA file inside my flutter app

Tags: flutter, apk, ipa

I need to compile on-the-fly (within a smartphone) a flutter code into APK/IPA file **inside my flutter app**.
How to do it?

Comment: Is your question related to the following? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015321/run-flutter-builder-runner-in-compiled-app

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile dart code within a flutter app. The architecture doesn't have the ability to compile or build an apk/ipa within flutter app. In short you cannot create apps within apps with flutter. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: So I can't do that?